# I need to generate a pdf page using jsp

Tags: java, html, mysql, css

I need to create PDF output in jsp. The code is actually generating in the form a brochure which contains profile information but in HTML format. So, I wanted that HTML output to be converted into PDF format, and also it should not display "headers and footers" while printing! I've now installed "itext" too, but I'm not getting how to use to generate PDF file.

Comment: Did you look at : `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6283336/generate-pdf-in-java-from-jsp` and `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386233/display-pdf-in-browser-using-java-servlet`  ?

Comment: The book iText in Action provides in depth details on how to generate pdfs. If you can't get the book a very simple [google search of itext html to pdf would get you enough details to get started](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=itext+create+pdf+from+html&spell=1)

Comment: One week before only, I had looked into it. I added those codes too. But it didn't help me to remove "headers & footers" in the print page. Plz help me in this! Thanx in advanz!