# pdf not rendering in IE10 using javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-10

I am running into an issue opening a pdf/rtf link in our application. Ideally when the user clicks on the link the 'attachment' it should be rendered in a new tab in the browser.
But in IE 10 it only renders gibberish.
This is what we used and worked in IE 7 which we have been been using for a while.

```
<a href="<%=row.fileName%>" target="_blank">My_attachmentpdf</a>
```

But when I opened some other pdf online in the same IE 10 it worked fine.
I was thinking may be I should try to force it to save to disk locally as an alternative.
Any thoughts?
PS: The application is j2ee web application and uses struts 1.0.
Thanks.

Comment: if you see `%PDF-1` at the start of the gibberish, then you're not sending out the appropriate mime headers and your pdf is being rendered as text/plain or text/html.

Comment: so you don't have the right mime headers to tell IE you're sending a PDF, so it's defaulting to plain text.

Comment: How do I do that in javascript? the `row.fileName` in the original post gives out `\myApp\myPdf1.pdf`.

Comment: there's nothing you can do in JS. it's something you have to fix on the server.

Comment: @MarcB I think I should try something like this below. But I don't have the ServletResponse object. Is there another option I can try? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386233/display-pdf-in-browser-using-java-servlet)