# How to show video from filelocation in servlets

Tags: java, file, servlets

I want to show video from folder(which is other than project folder). I did it using servlet as follows

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class Video extends HttpServlet {


    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
             throws IOException
    {
        response.setContentType("video/mp4");
        ServletOutputStream out;
        out = response.getOutputStream();
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("D:/7-4/Html/myvideo");

        BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(fin);
        BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(out);
        int ch =0;
        while((ch=bin.read())!=-1)
        {
            bout.write(ch);
        }

        bin.close();
        fin.close();
        bout.close();
        out.close();
    }
}
```

But when i run the project that webpage cannot run using browser's video plugin(it can run mp4 video). But when i tried to save it(using cntr+s) it got saved correctly please tell me proper way to achieve this. 
     I know it is working to show images and pdfs but when it come to video the browser cannot run the video that's why i asked this question

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the `Content-Type` of your response using this line of code:

`response.setContentType("video/mp4");`

The browser will examine the `Content-Type` header in the response to determine how to process your video file.

If you are returning a video other than mp4, you should specify the correct `Content-Type` value in your response. Otherwise, the browser will be unable to play the video correctly.

Please see http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/ for the right `Content-Type` value to return for videos with different extensions.

EDIT: 
It looks like your original code is writing integers into the output stream instead of bytes. Essentially you are converting the original video file into a stream of numbers and writing the numbers back. This should be the right way to read the video file:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class Video extends HttpServlet {


    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
         throws IOException
    {
        response.setContentType("video/mp4");
        ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("D:/7-4/Html/myvideo");

        byte [] buf = new byte[4096];
        int read;
        while((read = fin.read(buf)) != -1)
        {
            out.write(buf, 0, read);
        }

        fin.close();
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using a browser that supports video playback? Did you try with other browsers?

Comment: yes i tried with all the browsers

Comment: problem is in your code. see my updated response

Comment: which version of jdk you are using

Comment: it shouldn't matter. what problems are you encountering?

Comment: sorry missed out a parameter in the line: out.write(buf, 0, read);

Comment: out.write(buf, read); this method doesn't exist this method have1 or 3 parameters.

Answer (score 0):

To display files using Servlet, you need to specify at least 3 response headers: `Content-Type`, `Content-Disposition` and `Content-Length`.

The content type for mp4 is `video/mp4`. The content disposition will have to be `inline` and the content length will be the entire length of your data in bits.

So, just add the following before writing the data to response `OutputStream`:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename="+ fileName +";");
```

Where `fileName` is the exact name of the mp4 file.

See my [previously answered SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386233/display-pdf-in-browser-using-java-servlet#answer-7386373) with an example of how to accomplish this.

Comment: did it but still not working

Comment: You did what exactly?

Comment: i added response.setContentType("video/mp4");
    String fileName="myVideo.mp4";
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename="+ fileName +";");

Comment: Does your browser support mp4 inline? E.g., Safari will open QuickTime to display the video.

Comment: yes my browser supports i uses mozilla firefox i tried with chrome opera also but unfortunately nothing worked for me