# PDF doesn't display or download in browser java

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to display a pdf in the browser but it doesn't work,
It shows strange characters:

```
%PDF-1.4 %���� 3 0 obj <>stream x���n�������‑
C��͇[1]
�,ю��Țv=>�%���"=���ٯ�­
{�_�-�9�!�­Hu�a�Y�(`�E�c��]]������Չ��t�jsb�w�.>PV~P��
F\�z�oV?��'����S��Mb�$��`�߃������aLV�h䕴�����­�s��+���_�����������K�
�A�D����;[1]�[�I�'y���K�
��l[1]�
����,�I,2)
```

This is the method code in the controller:

```java
FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
try {      
      ExternalContext external = ctx.getExternalContext();
      HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) external.getResponse();
      OutputStream responseStream = response.getOutputStream();

      InputStream fileInputStream = evaluacionDataManager.getDatosEvaluacionEmpleado().getDocumento();
      byte[] pdf = IOUtils.toByteArray(fileInputStream);

      response.setContentType("application/pdf");
      response.setContentLength(pdf.length);  
      response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""
                 + "filename.pdf" + "\"");

      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("e:/aaaaaMG.pdf");
      fos.write(pdf);
      fos.close();

      responseStream.write(pdf);
      response.flushBuffer();     

} catch (Exception e) {
      logger.error("MENSAJE_CERTIFICACION", e);
      addErrorMessage(e.getMessage(), "");
}
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
```

The pdf `aaaaaMG.pdf` that is saved in the `e:` directory of the PC it's perfect, but the pdf displayed in the browser doesn't work.

I've tried with different content types but it appears to be that the headers aren't getting set.

I have also tried with:

```java
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + "filename.pdf" + "\"");
```

instead of `attachment` but it didn't solve my issue.

Any clue is welcome. Thanks

Comment: Similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386233/display-pdf-in-browser-using-java-servlet

Comment: did you try different browsers to check if they all show the same behaviour? It might be a browser problem, not a problem of the server.

Comment: Yes I have checked in Firefox and chrome and still got the same behaviour

Comment: Also I've read the similar issue but it's solution doesn't worked for me